# Using Babel option blacklist to exclude es6.classes but getting Fatal error: Bundling failed. undefined during grunt build?

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, babeljs, systemjs, jspm

```
System.config({
defaultJSExtensions: true,
transpiler: "babel",
babelOptions: {
"optional": [
  "runtime"
],
"blacklist": ['es6.classes'],
"nonStandard": false
},..................
```

Added blacklist option but not getting desired result for:

```
 $ grunt build
```

getting:

```
Running "bundle" task
Building
Fatal error: Bundling failed. undefined
```

Is anyone have solution to this problem?

Comment: Which babel version? Babel 6 doesn't support "blacklist" or "optional"

Comment: I'm using 5.8.24 version. Which version supports the "blacklist"  or "optional" ?